# Pull data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have 3 tables as follows :

> Table 1: *Product*
>
> ```
> id_product [Primary Key],added_time.
> ```
>
> Table 2: *Category*
>
> ```
> id_category [Primary Key],Category_name.
> ```
>
> Table 3: product_category
>
> ```
> id_category,id_product  [Both Foreign Keys]
> ```

I want to pull Data as

`Category_name`,`No Of Products` in this Category,`Last time` when product was added to Category(Latest product added_time).

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a free code writing service. I suggest you start yourself to code, do your research, try to learn, implement your approach. _Then_, if you run into a specific coding problem, _then_ is the time to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide few more details like table structure and what  you have tried for solving this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this `SQL`:

```
SELECT      Category.Category_name,
            Count(DISTINCT Product.id_product) AS num_products,
            Max(Product.added_time) last_added_time
FROM        Category
LEFT JOIN   product_category
       ON   product_category.id_category = Category.id_category
LEFT JOIN   Product
       ON   Product.id_product = product_category.id_product
GROUP BY    Category.Category_name;
```

Note that by using `LEFT JOIN` you will be certain to list all categories even those for which no products exist. If you don't want those, replace both `LEFT` keywords with `INNER`.

Note also that in standard `SQL` you need to `GROUP BY` any columns you mention in the `SELECT` list, unless they are aggregated, like with `MAX` or `COUNT`.

Comment: I want latest product image as well as last added time. How can i get that?

Comment: There is no mention of a product image in your original question. Could I ask you to please start a new question?

Comment: First table has one column named as FeaturedImage. id_product [Primary Key],added_time, featuredimage. I tried to get it using product.featuredimage but it gives image of another product

Comment: Please ask a new question (not here), and if you want, post the link to that new question here, and I will have a look at it. But I am sure there are enough people around that will help you, if you put a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.`Category_name`,
       (SUM(IF(P.`id_product`IS NULL,0,1))) AS No_of_Products,
        MAX(P.`added_time`) AS Latest_time
FROM
     Category C
LEFT JOIN 
      product_category P_C  ON C.`id_category` = P_C.`id_category`
LEFT JOIN 
      Product P ON  P.`id_product` = P_C.`id_product`
GROUP BY C.`id_category`
```

Hope this helps.